# writing results to a text file in python

Tags: python

I am reading a file with text and then passing it to extract noun phrases. The noun phrases are printing but when i write it to a text file, at time only the first phrases gets written or nothing ever gets written. Below is the code i have written to print to a text file.

Code below

```
import nltk
import re

file = open("C:\datafiles\entytest.txt", "r")
doclist = [ line for line in file ]
docstr = '' . join(doclist)
sentences = re.split(r'[.!?]', docstr)


grammar = '\n'.join([
  'NP: {<DT>*<NN>*<NN>}',
 ])

for sentence in sentences:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    chunkparser = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
    nnphrs = chunkparser.parse(tags)
    print(nnphrs)

f = open("C:\datafiles\nphrs.txt", "w")
for sentence in sentences:
    f.write("'%s',\n" %nnphrs)
f.close()
```

Comment: As an addition to the above (in the assumption you're fresh to python) indentation is key in python - your for loop at the start isn't doing anything because nothing is indented to indicate it is within the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to put the words in a txt file, you should store them **inside the loop**, like this:

```
f = open("C:\datafiles\nphrs.txt", "w")

for sentence in sentences:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    chunkparser = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
    nnphrs = chunkparser.parse(tags)
    f.write("'%s',\n" %nnphrs)
    print(nnphrs)
f.close()
```

Comment: Glad to know it, please validate the answer and give it a thumbs up !

Answer (score 0):

As Khelwood said, you are only parsing one sentence due to poor indentation.

Python, unlike many other languages is executed based on the spacing on the line. Blocks are part of loops and constructs when they are more indented than that loop.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html).

```
f = open("C:\datafiles\nphrs.txt", "w")    
for sentence in sentences:
   words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
   tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)
   chunkparser = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
   nnphrs = chunkparser.parse(tags)
   print(nnphrs)
   f.write("'%s',\n" %nnphrs)  
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use print to write to file:

```
with open("C:\datafiles\nphrs.txt", "w") as f:

    for sentence in sentences:
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
        tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)
        chunkparser = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
        nnphrs = chunkparser.parse(tags)

        print(nnphrs,file=f)
```